# How to remove scheduling in lumen

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks, lumen

Currently i am using PHP 5.6.32 and Laravel Framework Lumen (5.4.6) (Laravel Components 5.4.*).

I am able to schedule my task as per the specific time like below

```
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\SubjectController@frickcall', ["request" => $request])
            ->cron("14:23");
```

But after scheduling above call how could i remove it from scheduler list?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove that line of code from your schedule.

[Schedules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#introduction) are not jobs placed in a work queue in Laravel and Lumen, you are supposed to setup a cron job to run the scheduler every minute with a crontab entry like this:

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Then the schedule will be evaluated every minute to determine if anything needs to be run.

If you were meant to be using work queues look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues).